# What is the ontological status of the Combine framework's Never type?

Tags: ios, combine

In the Combine framework, what is the `Never` type exactly?

I don't mean how is it used or what does it signify; I understand that. I mean what is the what-it-is-to-be-a-Never (as Aristotle would say).

I ask because I can't find a declaration of any `Never` other than this one:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/never

But the Combine framework `Never` cannot be that `Never`, because the Combine `Never` has to be usable as a `Failure` type, and a `Failure` type can only be an `Error` adopter:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscriber/3213651-failure

But I can find no declaration that the `Never` in my first link adopts the `Error` protocol as required by my second link.

So I would expect to be able to find either (1) a place where that `Never` is declared to adopt the `Error` protocol or (2) the declaration of a completely different `Never`. But I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you’ve found the right `Never` and `Failure` definitions.

In answer to your ontological question, as it were, `Never` is an *uninhabited type.* See [SE-0102](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0102-noreturn-bottom-type.md).

The `Error` conformance can be found at [github.com/apple/swift/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1ed846d8525679d2811418a5ba29405200f6e85a/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift#L31).

FWIW, the peripherally related [SE-0215](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0215-conform-never-to-hashable-and-equatable.md) explicitly contemplates a `Never` as an `Error` type, too.

Comment: FYI, I’ve submitted web site feedback suggesting that they include the `Error` conformance for the `Never` type documentation.

Comment: I think what you're saying is what I actually suspected, namely, that Never gets some sort of behind-the-scenes magic dispensation that permits it to be used where an Error is expected without formally conforming to Error. This makes a certain sense when one considers the other things Never is permitted to do.

Comment: I remain somewhat disturbed, however, that the line of code `extension Never: Error {}` in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1ed846d8525679d2811418a5ba29405200f6e85a/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift#L31 is nowhere to be found in the documentation or the headers that I'm able to view from within Xcode.

Comment: If you `grep -r "extension Never" *` from the command line within the `Xcode.app` folder, you’ll see it in the various `.swiftinterface` files. It doesn’t make me feel better, but it is there. But, like you, I can’t find it within Xcode IDE, either. 

Comment: Note that because the `Error` protocol has no requirements, there is no behind-the-scenes magic needed beyond the (completely mundane) conformance declaration in `Policy.swift`.

Comment: Also, ontologically speaking, `Never` is an [initial object](https://youtu.be/zer1aFgj4aU) in the category of Swift types.